# MongoDB $lookup with multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have two collections in MongoDB, `items` and `categories`.
`items` is

```
{
  _id: "some_id",
  category_A: "foo",
  category_B: "bar",
}
```

and `categories` is

```
{
  _id: "foo_id",
  name: "foo",
  type: "A"  
},
{
  _id: "bar_id",
  name: "bar",
  type: "B"  
}
```

I'm trying to use a pipeline to get `foo_id` and `bar_id` by using `$lookup`, but I don't understand why the `category_A_out` array always returns empty.
Here is the relevant step of the pipeline for `category_A`:

```
{
  from: 'categories',
  "let": {
    "category": "$name",
    "type": "$type"
  },
  "pipeline": [{
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          { $eq: ["$category_A", "$$category"] },
          { $eq: ["$$type", "A"] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }],
  as: 'category_A_out'
}
```

I am sure that `foo` and `bar` exist in the `categories` collection.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` should use for declaring the variable for *LEFT collection* which is `items`.

If `category_A` holds the categories' name, you need match with `name`.

Else match with `_id`.

```
db.items.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "categories",
      "let": {
        "category_A": "$category_A"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$name",    // Or Match with $_id if category_A holds id
                    "$$category_A"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$type",
                    "A"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "category_A_out"
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7jC74hut6DD)

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I misunderstood the examples I found on the MongoDB documentation.